# SQL: How to add a column in the SELECT query result?

Tags: sql, select

Usually we will select the field(s) in the SQL query. e.g.

```
SELECT A.id FROM Member A
```

But what if I want to align a column which elements correspond to the other selected field?
For example I want to select the member ID from a member table, and the COUNT that count how many times the member appear in the tuple of other table

So how do I make the COUNT column that align together with the select result?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
SELECT A.id, count(B.MemberID) 
FROM Member A 
LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.id = B.MemberID
group by A.id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will include records in A that do not have any corresponding records in B. Also, `COUNT` only counts non-null values, so you need to use it with `B.MemberID`. This way the count for records in A that do not have any corresponding records in B will be 0, since `B.MemberID` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [@Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916759/sql-how-to-add-a-column-in-the-select-query-result/7916785#7916785)'s solution, but if there were many columns in the original SELECT list, they all would have to be listed in GROUP BY. I mean something like this:

```
SELECT
   A.id,
   A.name,
   A.whatever,
   ...
   COUNT(B.member_id)
FROM Member A
  LEFT JOIN Member_Something B ON A.id = B.member_id
GROUP BY
   A.id,
   A.name,
   A.whatever,
   ...
```

It is not always convenient, especially when the columns are actually expressions. You could take another approach instead:

```
SELECT
   A.id,
   A.name,
   A.whatever,
   ...
   COALESCE(B.member_count, 0)
FROM Member A
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS member_count
    FROM Member_Something
    GROUP BY member_id
  ) B ON A.id = B.member_id
```

Comment: @Andriy: I don't know about you, but CTRL-C and CTRL-V works on my OS with my keyboard :D  Seriously, good point.

Comment: @DanAndrews: Yeah, Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V are ever such a wonderful help, where would we be without it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select member_id, count(*)
from table
group by member_id;
```